# Distinct Counts in a Window Function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, distinct, window-functions

I'm trying to get a distinct count of rows within a window function that has multiple levels of partitioning. Below is a sample of my data.

| PRODUCT_ID | KEY_ID | STORECLUSTER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000078 | 120 | LLNY |
| 1000078 | 202 | LLF |
| 1000078 | 202 | LLNY |
| 1000078 | 202 | LLNY |

I want to look at each `PRODUCT_ID` and then each unique `KEY_ID` and determine how many unique `STORECLUSTERS` there are per `KEY_ID`. For example `PRODUCT_ID` 1000078 has two unique `KEY_ID`'s (120 and 202) of which 120 has 1 unique `STORECLUSTER` and 202 has 2 unqiue `STORECLUSTER`'s. I've tried using a `RANK()` and `DENSE_RANK()` but I can't seem to get the partitioning correct. I would like to get a table that looks like this:

| PRODUCT_ID | KEY_ID | STORECLUSTER | STORECLUSTER_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000078 | 120 | LLNY | 1 |
| 1000078 | 202 | LLF | 2 |
| 1000078 | 202 | LLNY | 2 |
| 1000078 | 202 | LLNY | 2 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not support `COUNT(DISTINCT` as a window function.

So you need to nest window functions. I find the simplest and most efficient method is `MAX` over a `DENSE_RANK`, but there are others.

The partitioning clause is the equivalent of `GROUP BY` in a normal aggregate, then the value you are `DISTINCT`ing goes in the `ORDER BY` of the `DENSE_RANK`. So you calculate a ranking, while ignoring tied results, then take the maximum rank, per partition.

```sql
SELECT
  PRODUCT_ID,
  KEY_ID,
  STORECLUSTER,
  STORECLUSTER_COUNT = MAX(rn) OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT_ID, KEY_ID)
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT_ID, KEY_ID ORDER BY STORECLUSTER)
    FROM YourTable t
) t;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=55b994c1cbbfb96e3bc9e2706b590de9)